# How to use Arcpy to set Extent to "Union of Inputs"

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-2.7

When I try to append two polygon feature classes, I get a geometry domain error. When using just ArcMap, I know that setting the processing extent to union of inputs fixes the issue.

However, how do I do that using arcpy, I know you can set a specific extent, but am not sure how to turn on the Union of Inputs option found under processing extent in ArcMap itself using only python.

Using Python 2.7.5 and ArcGIS 10.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will set the output extent parameter to include all inputs.

```
arcpy.env.extent = "MAXOF"
```